# How to write to a file?

Tags: c, file

I'm a bit stuck in a seemingly simple issue of writing contents into a file.

There is a function declared as `void decode_log(uint8_t *data, uint32_t len)` which prints some information in the debug terminal as follows:

```c
#define LOG_HEADER_LENGTH (16)
#define LOG_ENTRY_LENGTH (16)

static void decode_log(uint8_t *data, uint32_t len)
{
    if(len<LOG_HEADER_LENGTH)
    {
        DEBUG_Print("Log header missing!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        DEBUG_Print("\n=== USAGE_LOG ===\n"
            "Power cycles: %u\n"
            "Unpause events: %u\n"
            "Power-on time: %us\n"
            "Unpaused time: %us\n",
            get_uint32(data+0),
            get_uint32(data+4),
            get_uint32(data+8),
            get_uint32(data+12));
    }
    data+=LOG_HEADER_LENGTH;
    len-=LOG_HEADER_LENGTH;

    if(!len)
    {
        DEBUG_Print("No phase entries\n");
        return;
    }

    DEBUG_Print("Phase\tcount\tmin ms\tmax ms\ttotal ms\n");
    int phase_num=0;
    while(len>=LOG_ENTRY_LENGTH)
    {
        DEBUG_Print("%u\t%u\t%u\t%u\t%u\n", phase_num,
            get_uint32(data+0),
            get_uint32(data+4),
            get_uint32(data+8),
            get_uint32(data+12));
        phase_num++;
        data+=LOG_ENTRY_LENGTH;
        len-=LOG_ENTRY_LENGTH;
    }
    if(len)
    {
        DEBUG_Print("Incomplete entry for phase %d\n", phase_num);
    }

}
```

The `DEBUG_Print` above simply uses `printf` and is defined with:

```
#define DEBUG_Print(...) do{printf(__VA_ARGS__); fflush(stdout); }while(0)
```

The above code snipped decodes `data` and prints it into the debug terminal.

Now I want to save the same information into a file. Can you show me where and how to define, open and write the contents into a file, please?

Comment: How about [`fprintf()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)?

Comment: @AcidResin I thought so, much appreciate it if you could show me where exactly to open and how to decoded contents (as above) into a file using `fprintf`?

Comment: What is `DEBUG_Print()`? Does that use `printf()`?

Comment: @AcidResin , yes It simply uses `printf` , I just edited the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Declare a file pointer
FILE *file = NULL;

// Open the file for writing
file = fopen("filename.log", "w");
if(file == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: Cannot open file.\n");
    return;
}

// Write to file
fprintf(file, "\n=== USAGE_LOG ===\n");
...

// Always close the file if you don't need it anymore
// This also flushes the content as soon as possible
fclose(file);
```

Also, take note that the file's content's are emptied right after it's opened. If you don't want it to, use `file = fopen("filename.log", "a");` to add new logs to the file.

Comment: @thanks for the answer and feedback, here how to make the file print in the default project directory?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica I will edit the `fopen()`, but is `wt` really non-standard? I used `-pedantic` in gcc but it still compiled i.e. it's part of C Standard

Comment: @vtcSru Is the directory the same as where the program is?

Comment: AcidResin `"t"` really is non-standard.  gcc does not defined what is standard in C, even with _-pedantic_.  `"t"`  is not listed in the C spec and "If the string is one of the following, the file is open in the indicated mode. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined".  Your call.

Comment: I guess so. [Here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) it only says it's ignored, but I guess this isn't that much reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening the file from the calling function of this decode log. If multiple threads are calling this function, we might have to use the locks.

Here's an example using `fopen` inside the function but there may be better way to do it:

```
void decode_log(uint8_t *data, uint32_t len)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("debug.txt", "ab");

    if(len<LOG_HEADER_LENGTH)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"Log header missing!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(fp,"\n=== USAGELOG ===\n"
            "Power cycles: %u\n"
            "Unpause events: %u\n"
            "Power-on time: %us\n"
            "Unpaused time: %us\n",
            (uint32_t *)(data+0),
            (uint32_t *)(data+4),
            (uint32_t *)(data+8));
    }
    data+=LOG_HEADER_LENGTH;
    len-=LOG_HEADER_LENGTH;

    if(!len)
    {

        fprintf(fp,"No phase entries\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return;
    }

    fprintf(fp,"Phase\tcount\tmin ms\tmax ms\ttotal ms\n");
    int phase_num=0;
    while(len>=LOG_ENTRY_LENGTH)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"%u\t%u\t%u\t%u\t%u\n", phase_num,
            (uint32_t *)(data+0),
            (uint32_t *)(data+4),
            (uint32_t *)(data+8));
        phase_num++;
        data+=LOG_ENTRY_LENGTH;
        len-=LOG_ENTRY_LENGTH;
    }
    if(len)
    {
        fprintf(fp,"Incomplete entry for phase %d\n", phase_num);
    }

    fclose(fp);


}
```